# Do Secondary Casters need to know a ritual?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, rituals

The ritual rules state that you must know it, but thats in a paragraph talking about primary casters: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=777

> When you take charge of a ritual, you are its primary caster, and others assisting you are secondary casters. You can be a primary caster for a ritual even if you can’t cast spells. You must know the ritual, and the ritual’s spell level can be no higher than half your level rounded up. You must also have the required proficiency rank in the skill used for the ritual’s primary check (see Checks below), and as the primary caster, you must attempt this skill check to determine the ritual’s effects.

It doesn't mention knowing it under the secondary caster section specifically, but I'm not really clear on if the first mention applies to all casters or just primary ones due to its context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Only the Primary Caster needs to know

While you are correct in that there isn't (to my knowledge) a specific mention that secondary casters don't need to know a ritual, it never says they do. From the text you quote, that you are worried may apply to all casters (emphasis mine):

> ... **You** can be a primary caster for a ritual even if you can’t cast spells. **You** must know the ritual, and the ritual’s spell level can be no higher than half **your** level rounded up. **You** must also have the required proficiency rank in the skill used for the ritual’s primary check (see Checks below), and *as the primary caster*, you...

This paragraph uses you to refer to the primary caster, i.e. the one who knows the ritual. In all of the other instances of "You" in this paragraph, it is clear they are referring to one person, not multiple, since a ritual can only have one primary caster! So, in lack of any stated requirement that the secondary casters need to know a ritual, it is safe to say only the primary caster does.

In other news, this is a great data point for why we should standardize "y'all" as part of English. It's helpful to know when we mean second person plural vs second person singular. *steps off soapbox*